# Format Data Label_ DataLabelselection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

Tags: vba

I am unable to format the label , a number, using .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00".
Do let me know where the error lies.

```
 Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
 Set sh = Worksheets("Rounding")
 ch.Activate
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text = sh.Range("b2")          
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabel.Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid select and active whenever possible.

You are trying to apply the NumberFormat to the `DataLabels` collection not the `DataLabel`.  Omit `Selection` it is not a method of `DataLabel` or  `DataLabels`.

This is how it should be done:

```
Set sh = Worksheets("Rounding")
With sh.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    .SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    .SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text = FormatNumber(sh.Range("b2").Value)
    .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End With
```

Comment: @MathInquiry does your chart have Data labels already?

Comment: @MathInquiry I just retested the code and it works.  Are you sure that you have the right `SeriesCollection`?

Comment: yes, i have the right collection, infact the label gets selected on Select command but not the formatting

Comment: @MathInquiry Sorry that I missed it.  `DataLabel.Text` takes a string as an argument.  You will need to assign `DataLabel.Text`  the formatted numbers string value.  I updated my answer.

Comment: still not giving the expected result. I appreciate your effort to fix it.

Comment: ,Any luck on this!